# Consulta sql não retorna os dados corretos

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, query

estou tentando usar a consulta **SELECT SUBSTRING** mas não funciona como eu esperava. alguém pode me ajudar.

bom tenho uma coluna na minha tabela chamada **message** e nela contém alguns dados com quebras de linhas e etc.
Vou mostrar como os dados estão na coluna:

```
---------------------------------------
*Nº DO PEDIDO:* 7050/15-9-2021
*DATA:* 15-9-2021
*HORA:* 10:33:3
```

Sendo assim eu precisaria pegar apenas o número do pedido. então para isso realizo a consulta da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(message,56, 69) FROM `messages` WHERE status = 'Pendente'
```

Porém a consulta me retorna dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, a consulta até pega o Início do que eu desejo mas não encerra onde preciso! Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que comentou o tamanho pode variar, e por isso o `SUBSTRING(message,56, 69)` nem sempre traz o valor correto.

Nesse caso, pode usar a função [`LOCATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate), que basicamente procura uma string dentro de outra e retorna a posição.

Vamos imaginar que no campo mensagem tem o seguinte conteúdo:

```
'*QUALQUER COISA* 1234 *Nº DO PEDIDO:* 7050/15-9-2021    *DATA:* 15-9-2021 *HORA:* 10:33:3'
```

Se executar a função assim `SELECT LOCATE('*Nº DO PEDIDO:*', message, 1) from messages;` iria retornar 23, ou seja, "*Nº DO PEDIDO:*" começa na posição 23

E para saber onde termina poderia fazer  `SELECT LOCATE('*DATA:*', message, 1) from messages;`, quer iria retornar 43, ou seja, queremos pegar a substring que começa em 23 + 15, porque 15 é o tamanho da string "*Nº DO PEDIDO:*", e pegar um número de caracteres que vá até 43, que podemos saber subtraindo 43 - 23 - 15, que ficaria assim:

`SELECT SUBSTRING(message, 38, 16) FROM messages;` e iria retornar "7050/15-9-2021".

Agora que expliquei o conceito vem um segundo problema, se o tamanho variar, essa conta "fixa" vai falhar, que deve ser o seu caso, então basta substituir os numeros pelas respectivas funções `LOCATE` que usamos para calcular, assim:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(message, 
                 LOCATE('*Nº DO PEDIDO:*', message, 1)+15, 
                 LOCATE('*DATA:*', message, 1)-LOCATE('*Nº DO PEDIDO:*', message, 1)-15)
  FROM messages;
```

E pronto, teremos o resultado esperado. Criei um pequeno exemplo com valores diferentes nos campos para demonstrar o resultado, claro esperando que *"*Nº DO PEDIDO:*"* e *"*DATA:*"* não mudem, senão o `LOCATE` não vai retornar os valores corretos.
Pode ver funcionando aqui: [https://www.db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8CPLkLseDUKwoMQdJE9QSb/0)

Sinceramente não é um código bonito, mas atende. Como sugestão, deveria transformar isso numa estrutura mais interável, como um json por exemplo.

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado Ricardo. de fato sua explicação me ajudou muito e com o código, consegui realizar alguns ajustes e ficou sensacional. Muito obrigado mesmo. NOTA 1000 pra você